# How to create array with values that exists in longer array and does not exists in shorter array?

Tags: php

Have 2 php arrays.

One array is created from input values (array named `$date_and_currency_array_for_comparision`).

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CurrencyAbbreviation] => USD
            [DateOfCurrencyRate] => 2013-07-22
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [CurrencyAbbreviation] => CAD
            [DateOfCurrencyRate] => 2013-07-11
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [CurrencyAbbreviation] => CZK
            [DateOfCurrencyRate] => 2013-07-31
        )

)
```

Another array is created from values in mysql (named `data_select_currency_rate`)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CurrencyAbbreviation] => CAD
            [DateOfCurrencyRate] => 2013-07-11
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [CurrencyAbbreviation] => CZK
            [DateOfCurrencyRate] => 2013-07-31
        )

)
```

Need to create array with values from first array if these values does not exist in the second array.

At first tried

```
$currencies_that_must_insert_into_mysql = array_diff_assoc($date_and_currency_array_for_comparision, $data_select_currency_rate);
```

But get incorrect results. For example know that in mysql there is no `[CurrencyAbbreviation] => USD` but `$currencies_that_must_insert_into_mysql` shows `[CurrencyAbbreviation] => CZK`.

Then tried this

```
$data_difference = array();
foreach ($date_and_currency_array_for_comparision as $key_longer_array => $value_longer_array){

  foreach ($data_select_currency_rate as $key_shorter_array => $value_shorter_array){

    if ( 
    ($value_longer_array[CurrencyAbbreviation] != $value_shorter_array[CurrencyAbbreviation]) 
    and ($value_longer_array[DateOfCurrencyRate] != $value_shorter_array[DateOfCurrencyRate]) ) {

    $data_difference[$key_longer_array][CurrencyAbbreviation] = $value_longer_array[CurrencyAbbreviation];
    $data_difference[$key_longer_array][DateOfCurrencyRate] = $value_longer_array[DateOfCurrencyRate];

}

  }

   }
```

But, if the second array is blank (no values in mysql), then `print_r($data_difference)` also shows nothing. And possibly there are other problems.

Please advice how to create array with values that exists in longer array and does not exists in shorter array

Comment: Think you are just missing some quotes, `$value_longer_array[CurrencyAbbreviation]` should be `$value_longer_array['CurrencyAbbreviation']`

Comment: please put your code in phpfiddle.com and give us a link to test with you

Comment: @FaceOfJock I put it here http://xfiddle.com/main/php/one_array_from_two_30465aca.php but... errors `Undefined index`. Actually it works not the same way as on website

Comment: give me only code of your arrays,values.

Comment: `$date_and_currency_array_for_comparision = array
(
array("CurrencyAbbreviation",'USD','CAD','CZK'),
array("DateOfCurrencyRate",'2013-07-22','2013-07-11','2013-07-31'),
);`

and 
`$data_select_currency_rate = array
(
array("CurrencyAbbreviation",'CAD','CZK'),
array("DateOfCurrencyRate",'2013-07-11','2013-07-31'),
);` If i correctly understand what is necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it. You just need to [count the number of elements in second array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php). If it is zero, just assign the first array to `$data_difference`. Otherwise, perform the loop you have.

Also, remember to quote the keys of your array when they are in string format.

```
$data_difference = array();

// If second array is empty, put the contents of first array into $data_difference.
if (0 == count ($data_select_currency_rate))
{
   $data_difference = $date_and_currency_array_for_comparison;
}
else
{
   foreach ($date_and_currency_array_for_comparision as $key_longer_array => $value_longer_array)
   {
      foreach ($data_select_currency_rate as $key_shorter_array => $value_shorter_array)
      {
         // Remember to quote the key/index of the array.
         if ( 
             ($value_longer_array['CurrencyAbbreviation'] != $value_shorter_array['CurrencyAbbreviation']) 
             and ($value_longer_array['DateOfCurrencyRate'] != $value_shorter_array['DateOfCurrencyRate']) )
         {
            $data_difference[$key_longer_array]['CurrencyAbbreviation'] = $value_longer_array['CurrencyAbbreviation'];
            $data_difference[$key_longer_array]['DateOfCurrencyRate'] = $value_longer_array['DateOfCurrencyRate'];

         }

      }

   }
}
```

Comment: Appears very simple. I even can not believe, that there are no "underwater rocks". At first sight all works as necessary, but after some days when work with other part of code, appears, that previously created code is not correct... and need to "go back" and correct

Comment: There is problem in my logic. If 'CurrencyAbbreviation' `AND` 'DateOfCurrencyRate' is not the same. Hovewer in mysql there may be the same 'DateOfCurrencyRate' and not the same 'CurrencyAbbreviation'. `OR` also can not help. Seems need to combine the both values from input and mysql and then check the combined value....

Comment: Do you mean you want to filter the value with the same 'CurrencyAbbreviation' but different 'DateOfCurrencyRate'? In that case, in your `if()` statement, just remove the `and ($value_longer_array['DateOfCurrencyRate'] != $value_shorter_array['DateOfCurrencyRate'])` part. Otherwise, you might need to post more details for us to see.

Comment: I mean, for example, in mysql there may be only value for `USD` `2013-07-01` and my input may be `USD` `2013-07-02`. As in mysql there is no such value I need to insert it. But with condition `AND` this value would not be in `$data_difference`. So at the moment decided combine values, for example, like `USD2013-07-02` and `USD2013-07-01` and then in `if` to compare the combined/united values

Comment: In that case, create two arrays to store the values you want to insert to your database. First one is `$data_difference`, which is what we already have above. The second one, let's call it `$data_new`. This will be value with same currency different date. You can get it by checking for item with same `CurrencyAbbreviation` but different `DateOfCurrencyRate`.

Comment: Put this in the same `foreach()` loop above and see if it accomplishes what you want:
`if (($value_longer_array['CurrencyAbbreviation'] == $value_shorter_array['CurrencyAbbreviation']) and ($value_longer_array['DateOfCurrencyRate'] != $value_shorter_array['DateOfCurrencyRate'])) { $data_new[$key_shorter_array]['CurrencyAbbreviation'] = $value_shorter_array['CurrencyAbbreviation']; $data_new[$key_shorter_array]['DateOfCurrencyRate'] = $value_shorter_array['DateOfCurrencyRate']; }`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36279/discussion-between-sutandiono-and-user2465936)

Answer (score 1):

```
$data_difference = array();
foreach ($date_and_currency_array_for_comparision as $key_longer_array =>$value_longer_array){

 if(count($data_select_currency_rate)>0)
 {
 foreach ($data_select_currency_rate as $key_shorter_array => $value_shorter_array){

 if ( 
 ($value_longer_array[CurrencyAbbreviation] != $value_shorter_array[CurrencyAbbreviation]) 
and ($value_longer_array[DateOfCurrencyRate] != $value_shorter_array[DateOfCurrencyRate]) ) {

$data_difference[$key_longer_array][CurrencyAbbreviation] = $value_longer_array[CurrencyAbbreviation];
$data_difference[$key_longer_array][DateOfCurrencyRate] = $value_longer_array[DateOfCurrencyRate];

}

 }

  }
 else
 {
   $data_difference[$key_longer_array][CurrencyAbbreviation] = $value_longer_array[CurrencyAbbreviation];
   $data_difference[$key_longer_array][DateOfCurrencyRate] = $value_longer_array[DateOfCurrencyRate];
}

 }
```